# How to serialized ICollection to transmit it from client to server

Tags: entity-framework, wcf

I have EntityFramework autogenerated clsses, and I want to serialized them to transmit to server. For example:

```
 [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
     [KnownType(typeof(ObservableCollection<UserProp>))]
    public partial class DirectionWork
    {

        public DirectionWork()
        {
        this.UserProp = new HashSet<UserProp>();
    }
    [DataMember]
    public int IdDirectionOfWork { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string DirectionWork1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<UserProp> UserProp { get; set; }
}
```

but I can't Serialized objects like ICollection. How can I fix this problem?